In Linux, which option is faster: to post/unlock a semaphore/mutex or to create a new thread?
I have an application running in Linux. It has a thread for real-time control, which implies that this thread must run periodically (with a period of approximatelly 200 microsseconds) and that it must provide an output within a known time limit. The thread for real-time control has attributes for preemptive scheduling and currently runs fine. It runs in Raspberry Pi 3 and has very low memory consumption, so memory is not an issue, the biggest concern is CPU usage.
Upon certain conditions, the real-time thread has to trigger the execution of another task. Although this other task is CPU intensive, it is not a real-time task, so it doesn't need to run in preemptive scheduling.
My questions are: among the options below, does any of them consume significantly less CPU time on the real-time thread? Why? Is there a more efficient solution to this problem?
Option A) To create a new thread for the non-real-time task with the pthread_create function whenever it must be executed.
Option B) To create a thread for the non-real-time task only once and leave it waiting on a mutex/semaphore that would be unlocked/posted by the real-time thread.
Example for option A:
void*
not_real_time_thread(void* args)
{
    // do non-real-time things
    return (void*) EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void*
real_time_thread(void* args)
{
    sem_t sync;
    sem_init(&sync, 0, 0);
    int end_event=0; 
    int running=1;

    int trigger_other_task = 0;
    pthread_t not_real_time_thread_handle;
    pthread_attr_t thread_attrs;    // Thread attributes
    // init thread_attrs properly

    // Real-time section
    while(running)
    {
        // do real time things
        if(trigger_other_task)
        {
            pthread_create(&not_real_time_thread_handle, &thread_attrs, not_real_time_thread, NULL);
        }
        if(end_event)
        {
            running=0;
        }
    }
    sem_destroy(&sync);

    return (void*) EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Example for option B:
int g_running;
sem_t g_semaphore;

void*
not_real_time_thread(void* args)
{
    while(g_running)
    {
        sem_wait(&g_semaphore);
        // do non-real-time things
    }
    return (void*) EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void*
real_time_thread(void* args)
{
    sem_t sync;
    sem_init(&sync, 0, 0);
    int end_event=0; 
    g_running=1;

    int trigger_other_task = 0;
    sem_init(&g_semaphore, 0, 0);
    pthread_t not_real_time_thread_handle;
    pthread_attr_t thread_attrs;    // Thread attributes
    // init thread_attrs properly
    pthread_create(&not_real_time_thread_handle, &thread_attrs, not_real_time_thread, NULL);

    // Real-time section
    while(g_running)
    {
        // do real time things
        if(trigger_other_task)
        {
            sem_post(&g_semaphore);
        }
        if(end_event)
        {
            g_running=0;
        }
    }
    sem_destroy(&sync);

    int thread_result=0;
    pthread_join(not_real_time_thread_handle, (void*) &thread_result;
    sem_destroy(semaphore);
    return (void*) EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Thanks in advance for the attention.

Typically, creating a new thread is pretty expensive.  I would not expect that to outperform unlocking a mutex or posting to a semaphore, but as with all things performance, you need to test.

Reading glibc sources shows that mutex will always be faster if there are no threads waiting for it and will cost one syscall if there are. And judging by kernel sources that syscall is pretty cheap compared to clone.
But depending on what you want other process to do, you may want to use more complex form IPC. Pipe/fifo, message queue, signals, something else in userspace shared memory(for example ring buffers) and process priority changes(including (un)pausing process).

I do use a message queue to pass data between threads. If it is cheaper, it would be a good choice. Nevertheless, I am excited to test the mutex approach. Thank you very much! I will test it on monday, when I'm back to work.

Also I forgot to mention signals. They are basically userspace interrupts. Or if all you want after receiving message is only exec(), then you might use vfork+exec or posix_spawn.
